# Django custom manager for Users

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to filter a queryset in custom manager to filter differently for different Users. I want one employee should have access to data in a particular range of dates only.

```
class UserWiseManager(models.manager)
  .
  .
class ItemsSold(models.Model):
  date = model.DateField()
  item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  objects = UserWiseManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass User instance directly to the manager, like this:

```
class UserWiseQuerySet(models.QuerySet)

    def for_user(self, user):
        if user.is_anonymous():
            return self.filter(date__gte=(now() - timedelta(days=1))
        else:
            return self

UserWiseManager = UserWiseQuerySet.as_manager()

class ItemsSold(models.Model):
    date = model.DateField()
    item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objects = UserWiseManager()


def view(request):
    items = ItemsSold.objects.for_user(request.user)
```